# two column sidebar not rendering correctly

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

This site used to look fine and then wordpress was upgraded.  There were no other changes.  The sidebar starts as one column and then splits into two columns.  The two columns are set in two divs one floating left, and one floating right.  It looks fine in FF on a mac, but that's it.  It's messed up on Safari on mac, and the major browsers on a pc.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Here's the full site, if you want to view source code: http://girlgonemom.com/

Here's the css:

```
#content {
border-right:2px solid #abcfcb;
margin: 20px;
width:630px;
float:center;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#primary {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
width: 310px;
}
#secondary {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
width: 150px;
}
#third {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 5px;
width: 150px;
list-style-type:none;

}
```

Comment: couldnt find the problem. using chrome

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the `third div`.  I think you commented it out?  In any event, you should try the following...

1. try to `float` the `third div` left as well
2. more importantly, reduce both the `secondary` and `third` divs.  Start at `5px` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `width: 310px;` in both `#secondary` and `#third` instead of the `width: 150px` that they have.

Theres still some alignment 'problems' going on with some of the ads even after that. But you can add `text-align: center;` `to your #secondary` and then `text-align: left;` to your secondary's title `#secondary #text-17 h3`

This is what fixes it:

```
#content {
border-right:2px solid #abcfcb;
margin: 20px;
width:630px;
float:center;
padding-right: 10px;
}
#primary {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
width: 310px;
}
#secondary #text-17 h3 { text-align: left; }
#secondary {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
width: 310px;
text-align: center;
}
#third {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 5px;
width: 310px;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

Not really necessary but since this was really easy, heres example of it with the added code: http://www.csspivot.com/R7CUE

**Edit:** Didnt take some things into account before..

**Edit2:** If i could just learn to read one of these days. well, this solution will make it one column just like you wanted. You just didnt know it yet :)

Comment: This didn't fix it.  I don't want it to be one column, I want the second and third sidebars to be next to each other - ultimately making two columns.

Comment: The structure of your sidebar is.. one that doesnt quite.. like to do that. Let me try to explain. Inside `#secondary` you have these separate elements that pretty much hold one ad each one and `#third` is one of those and is inside `#secondary` as well so its not really third but a child element to `#secondary`. You should divide the ads in two and put them in 2 different widgets instead of multiple ones.